# How to keep Pandora / Slacker music apps continue to play music after the display goes dark?

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, settings, music, pandora

I'm running android 4.4.2. When I play music via the Pandora or Slacker apps, it works fine. But if I stop using the phone while its playing, then the music stops playing once the current song ends.

So if a song is already playing when the screen goes dark, it will keep playing, but once it ends, it doesn't fetch the next song.

If I keep my display active, then the songs keep playing without any problem.

My research in this indicates that this is an issue with the wifi being cut off once the phone is inactive, which prevents the app from getting the next song. But I already have the setting 'Keep wifi on during sleep' set to 'always', but it has no effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have any "battery-saving" apps, they may turn off your data/Wi-Fi while your phone is sleeping. Be sure to check those first.

Also, depending on your phone, you can go to **Settings > Wi-Fi > [Menu] > Advanced > Best Wi-Fi Performance** and toggle that on to see if it helps.